# Is this the appropriate place to ask questions about how to accomplish an effect in Photoshop when there is clearly no relation to photography?

Tags: discussion, support

Although I'm usually not interested in graphic design, I currently have a question about how to accomplish a certain effect in Photoshop.

I understand that photo.se is about "Photography and Photographic Editing" - **are questions that aren't about editing an photo** (as in, you took the photo with a camera) **but about editing something created purely in Photoshop appropriate here?**

Comment: There is a graphic design proposal that would seem to fit this very closely (though not in beta yet, so not immediately helpful): http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1924/graphic-design

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably not; it's not photography. That's not to say that there aren't people that can answer that question, but this is a photography site, not a graphic arts one. The better question might be to ask is should this site expand to encompass visual arts as a whole? After all, videography questions are, technically, not photographic questions either, though they are far closer than software only options.

Comment: I'd tend to agree; the design aspects of photoshop go *way* beyond what's used for photo editing.

Comment: I would have to agree with this. Photoshop questions are okay as long as they relate to photo manipulation. I would *love* to see a site on the graphic arts, though! Commit: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1924/graphic-design