# Where do we draw the line on Photoshop and similar questions?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, photoshop

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Where is the right stackexchange site to post photoshop questions (here or superuser) ?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1259/where-is-the-right-stackexchange-site-to-post-photoshop-questions-here-or-superu)
>   [Is this the appropriate place to ask questions about how to accomplish an effect in Photoshop when there is clearly no relation to photography?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289/is-this-the-appropriate-place-to-ask-questions-about-how-to-accomplish-an-effect)
>   [What should we do with Photoshop questions?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/658/what-should-we-do-with-photoshop-questions)

It's long been the site policy that [general photoshop questions](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/658/what-should-we-do-with-photoshop-questions) are off-topic, and so are photo-manipulation questions which only [happen to use a photograph as the base](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289/is-this-the-appropriate-place-to-ask-questions-about-how-to-accomplish-an-effect). I think generally, we've drawn the line like this: "how do I get a specific post-processing effect using software" questions have been considered on topic, while "how do I use a feature of a certain software package" questions not, *even when that feature **could** be used in photo processing*.

For example: [Mist Photoshop CS5 Effect](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6650/mist-photoshop-cs5-effect), [Apply an overlay layer to a single layer, and then adjust the result of that?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/2558/apply-an-overlay-layer-to-a-single-layer-and-then-adjust-the-result-of-that), and [Photoshop Pen tool](https://superuser.com/questions/236666/photoshop-pen-tool).

But we're really not consistent on this. Other times, Photoshop questions are asked and [get decent answers](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5358/linking-two-layer-masks-together-in-photoshop). And, we seem to be pretty harsh with how-do-I-operate-Photoshop questions, whereas general questions about Aperture or Lightroom are not blinked at — presumably because those programs are marketed more narrowly at photography workflow.

So:

1. Where do we want to draw this line? Is mentioning "I want to use this on a photo" sufficient? (See [Is there a way in Photoshop to apply a mask to a single Smart Filter?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13737/photoshop-apply-a-mask-to-a-single-smart-filter))
2. If that *is* sufficient, does it extend to basic concepts like the selection tool and layer manipulation? Do we have a strong "story" for *not* covering those things when someone wants to use them to work on a photo and doesn't know how?
3. We cover things like the business of photography, and art and composition basics, but seem to have a collective dislike of "artificial" image manipulation questions like the one about adding a mist effect. Can we explain that in a straightforward way that makes sense in the FAQ?

Or, I guess, to put it another way:

A) If we open up the site to [photoshopping gone wild](http://www.worth1000.com/), would that have a negative impact on the site? (Dilute our focus in some way?)

B) If we make photoshop questions more harshly off-topic (directing them all to superuser.com or graphicdesign-SE), does that provide a benefit? (More photography in its pure form, less [artifice](http://theonlinephotographer.typepad.com/the_online_photographer/2008/12/the-worst-photo.html)?)

C) Or, y'know, if we just keep handling these things in an ad hoc way, maybe that's fine. (Even then, would some FAQ clarification help?)

Comment: @Dori: none of those previous questions quite cover the precise question of where we draw the line. Asking a separate question was an attempt to focus the discussion on that.

Comment: One of those questions is very narrow: are definitely-non-photographic-effects questions on topic. Another asks where the best destination for anything decided to be off topic might be. And the third was asked at the same time I was writing this.

Comment: @dori I think it can be reopened for now, but let's be cognizant of previous discussion on the issue as well..

Answer (score 6):

So, I'm kind of inclined to say that we *should be more open to these questions*. Even if I've been harsh on them before. Specifically, in reference to what I said above:

1. We should accept any software questions where someone can basically include "with my photograph" or "for photography" or "photographic image" somewhere. Even if they really are photo-manipulation questions — those same skills are useful in a less-exaggerated degree in usually-considered-perfectly-tasteful retouching.
2. This would include really basic stuff, including driving the user interface, as long as it's *a real question* which shows the simple standard of having *tried* to figure it out — as long as they meet the "for my photo" standard. Failing that, we redirect to Superuser.
3. The FAQ should be updated to suggest that graphic design and layout-oriented questions go to Graphic Design, and that simple "how do I use software" questions are probably better suited for Superuser.

I say this because I have a hard time making a good explanation for why we would accept software questions *at all* without putting the line pretty far to that side. If we decided "cameras only; no computers!", we might have a defensible niche, but I think an unnecessarily small one in this modern age (especially since Stack Exchange *does* have a computer-oriented heritage.)

Comment: +1 couldn't agree more