# Correct process to dispute duplicate

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I'm new to PSE and wondered what the usual procedure is to dispute being marked as a duplicate? Oddly I've never disputed one on Stack Overflow.

The "duplicate" is for a similar but different problem so the solution is not valid for me.

Does it just require reopen votes? (being new here, I don't have access to tools/counts yet).

[The question in question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/34887/how-to-transform-image-to-be-projected-undistorted-onto-a-sphere)

Comment: If this isn't a duplicate, isn't it kinda off-topic?

Comment: @mattdm Quite possibly but I did read through your Q/A [here](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1260/where-do-we-draw-the-line-on-photoshop-and-similar-questions) and I believe you could easily add the words "with my photo" to my Q (In fact, I'm the upvote you got last night). I also believe I've passed the "tried to figure it out msyelf criteria". That said, I'm new here and am happy to be pointed to a more relevant SE site if you can recommend one

Comment: Okay, but there's still a line there somewhere. I mean, one could ask "how can I eat pudding, with my photo", and I'm pretty sure that would be off-topic. I don't have a very strong opinion on this particular one, but it doesn't really seem to be common thing I'd expect other people to be doing with photos. It's almost more like something that might apply to texture mapping for games....

Comment: @mattdm I don't really disagree - That is why I started the Q with "I'm not sure if this is the right SE site" (Before someone edited it out). That said, if the consensus is that it's the wrong site, perhaps a vote to transfer rather than close would be more useful for other questions like this in future. I'm far less convinced this is the right site than I am that it isn't a duplicate. In any case, thanks for taking the time to look

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's important to note here that closures are (generally) handled by the wider community, rather than the moderators. This same wider community can disagree with a closure and vote to reopen (And at time of writing, there are two votes to reopen on the example question).

It is also worth noting that we encourage questions about *Photography*, [and not *image manipulation in (photo) editing software*](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/q/289/21). There is a [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange site that handles graphic manipulation, which might be better suited for you...

Answer (score 2):

No real process. If you do not believe your question is a duplicate, you can state as much and discuss the issue in the comments below the question. If your question is not clear, or if there is a way to improve it such that the differences become more clear, you should edit your question appropriately.

Comment: I'm not really sure how I can be more explicit - I explain the effect I'm after (which isn't the same as in the one linked). I'd love to add an example but if I could do that, I wouldn't need to ask the question...

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the best bet is to make your case in the comments requesting that people vote to re-open and/or editing the question to try and differentiate it.  Both the comments and the revision history will be easily available if your question is in the Reopen review queue and will simplify the lives of people voting to either re-open or keep your question closed.